# How to reconstruct hash value to the original format?

Tags: cryptographic-hash-function

I would like to know how I can reconstruct a hash value such as 558f68181d2b0c9d57d41ce7aa36b71d9 to its original format (734).

I have used a code in matlab, which provided me with an hash output, but I tried to revers the operation to obtain the original value but no use. I tired converting from hex to binary but no use.

Are there any built in functions that can help me obtaining the original value?

i have used this code :

http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31272-datahash

Comment: There is a lot of interest in doing this - The whole purpose of the 'cryptographic hash' is to make it  'difficult' to get back to to the original value. ;-/ May I ask what  was the original problem, that you were given, that lead you to trying to reverse the hash as a useful approach?

Comment: thanks @RyanVincent I am trying to send a key from Alice to bob by hashing the key (Using MD5), and bob to be able to decrypt and retrieve the key. 

I also found a built in function for MD5 in matlab but I am not able to get any information how to use it.

Comment: I assume that 'Alice'  and  'Bob' have previously exchanged the 'symetric encryption  key'? This is _not about public  key encryption_. Bob needs to compare the 'hash' from Alice with the 'hash', that he generates, of the 'shared symetric key'. If they match - all ok - otherwise there is an error.

Comment: yes you are perfectly correct @RyanVincent , that what i am doing,, at the moment am working on the below code but it shows me matrix are not the same!!

Comment: s1 = 512;
s2 = 623;
s3 = 734; 
s1prime = 512;
s2prime = 623;
s3prime = 734;
r=15; 
AliceTX = strcat (num2str(r)  , fBase64_encc(s3)); 
AliceTX1 = xor(AliceTX,s1); % issue with key and xor
bob1 = xor((AliceTX1),(s1prime));
if bob1 == fBase64_encc(s3prime);
alice = xor((fBase64_encc(r)),(s2));
end

Comment: Are you creating your own hash function? Why? There are tried and tested ones available... see [Cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

Comment: @RyanVincent yah i already checked wiki page , i am not creating a new hash function , i am using codes i have already got online , i have added extra codes to serve my project it self. my problem is to get the hash value back :D which gives me the below error : Error using  == 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: This is 'well beyond my field of expertise'. It was enjoyable. I have no further suggestions.

Comment: thanks a lot for efforts @RyanVincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this is impossible. The whole idea of cryptographical hashes (like SHA-1 used above) is to be as unpredictable as possible. The hash of certain data should always be the same (of course) but it should be really hard to predict which data that resulted in a certain hash.

If you have a limited amount of values, you could probably create a lookup-table (hash -> data that made it) but this is actually the exact opposite of how they are supposed to be used.

I think you *want* to create your own hashing for this problem, where you could inline the data you hash in some particular way.

Comment: Dear @claj thanks a lot for your answer , in secret communication method i would like to cross check if my message is received correctly , in case i will hash the message how i can recompute the values it self.